# Canvas Check before submission

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a page where a user can draw on the canvas and save the image to a file on the server.
The canvas has a default black background. Is there a way to check if the user has drawn anything on the canvas before submitting the data URL representation of the image of a canvas with the toDataURL() function?  So if the user doesn't draw anything on the canvas(it will be a blank canvas with a black background), the image wont be created on the server. Should I loop through each and every pixel of the canvas to determine this? 
Here is what I'm doing currently:

```
var currentPixels  = context.getImageData(0, 0, 600, 400);
    for (var y = 0; y < currentPixels.height; y += 1) {

         for (var x = 0; x < currentPixels.width; x += 1) {
                for (var c = 0; c < 3; c += 1) {

                var i = (y*currentPixels.width + x)*4 + c;

                if(currentPixels.data[i]!=0)
                break;

                }

         }

  }
```

Comment: What is used to allow the user to draw? It probably have some sort of event or property that can be read.
If not, just read out the data from the canvas and inspect each pixel to find its color.

Comment: Is there any other approach instead of looping and checking each pixel?

Comment: That depends. What library are you using to allow the user to draw? This isn't a built-in feature after all.

Comment: I'm just using Canvas in FF..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that something is drawn on the canvas when you click on it, you could bind a click even to the canvas that set a flag indicating that the canvas has been drawn on.

For example using jQuery:

```
var canvasDrawnOn = false;

$("#canvas").click(function(){
    canvasDrawnOn = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this a while ago, but it doesn't suit my purposes.

First I take the image data in base64:

```
var imgdata = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Then I get an MD5 hash (I do this in PHP, but it doesn't matter; to do it in JavaScript you have to use a library, such as [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/md5)) of the image data:

```
var h = $.md5(imgdata);
```

After this, you can compare the MD5 with a pre-calculated hash of an empty canvas:

```
if(h == EMPTYCANVAS) ...
```

It doesn't work for me, since the user sets the image dimensions, and different size canvases would have a different hash. Suggestions for overcoming this (while avoiding traversing pixel by pixel) would be awesome.